# Cable TV works but Internet doesn’t after the cable company buried their cable connection to my place

Tags: internet, modem, cable, tv

New WOW! cable service was working fine. Then they buried the cable and now there is no Internet connection and some local channels are no longer there (AMC TBS etc. work fine but there seems to be a lot of pixelation on some channels).

I removed their modem and put my own Surfboard in and it could not be provisioned.

Been on the phone resetting each box multiple times with tech support to no avail.

Could anyone offer an explanation as to what could be happening?

Comment: This stinks and the reality is that this is something you should talk even more to your cable company about. We can’t really help. Ask them to send a technician out and — if you have neighbors with the same service — I would recommend asking them if they noticed similar stuff. If this is a signal strength issue, then this might affect more people than just you. Power in numbers via complaints will always win. Hope this works out!

Answer (score 2):

These are all signs of terrible signal strength. When they buried the cable, they must have damaged it or otherwise done something that greatly attenuates the signal.

They are going to have to "roll a truck" (send out a technician) and fix their cable.

The channels that still work okay are probably injected at higher signal level than the other channels, or they are on lower-frequencies that aren't attenuated as much by the cable.

Comment: Do they normally do a check of signal quality after burying the cable? I do have a service appointment scheduled. I was just unclear as to the why Internet and only some tv channels did not work.

Comment: @NeilBorkowicz - Technically, they should have never left, without verifying you had cable tv and internet.

Answer (score 0):

Put back the ISP cable modem. Connect a computer directly to a LAN port on this modem. Call the ISP Tech Support and ask them to view your modem. They can tell from the office if it is the modem or their line to the modem. They can do this so ask them for support

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I did this and they said they cannot see the modem.   I must have 6 RG cables under my lawn. What’s one more I guess.

Comment: That means the wiring to the modem is defective in some way. RG-6 cables are fine for cable and internet. The cable is the ISP responsibility.

Comment: Sorry John, I should have said half a dozen not 6 as I was referring to the sheer number that have put in over 25 years of switching carriers.  I did not mean RG-6. The cable they ran was RG-11 btw.

Comment: So it is an ISP issue as noted